# Using android WebView only with chrome

Tags: java, android, google-chrome

I can use web view to convert my web site to an android app using a simple tutorial like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a5dlmqM9Oo8

The issue is I don't know how to embed chrome in the app so that the users always open the website only with chrome?

The reason for this is I'm using web speech api and as you know this api only works in chrome.. So I need an android app of my web site which is only opens my website in chrome

Thanks in advance for any comment